# How do I decide a good bandwidth in an amplifier for DC measurement?

Tags: amplifier, bandwidth

I am looking at this [instrumentation amplifier (INA)](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8237.pdf). I want to have a gain of 1, so I must use the low bandwidth mode of the INA, which is 200kHz.

Is this bandwidth Ok to use for DC measurements? The two inputs to this INA are the outputs from this [isolated amplifier](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Famc1200).

How do I know if 200kHz is good or not?

Comment: Nothing is truly DC. So I guess the question is technically how long are you willing to wait to see a change in the DC.

Comment: so, the bandwidth just affects how long I will notice the difference but not the accuracy? How should I calculate the waiting time given the bandwidth?

Comment: Alex, my alarm bells are going off for possible common pitfalls for less-experienced analog designers.  If you are not confident of your design, consider sharing the schematic.  Continue to ask about your original concern, but also consider your noise goals and possible ground reference and common mode issues.  Best of luck!

Comment: It shouldn't affect the accuracy given the input signal stays the same for long enough for the output to catch up, though any noise present (which is AC) will alias but you may not care. There is an equation for 10-90% rise time versus bandwidth, but note it has limitations and conditions. I forget what they are though.

Comment: Thank you all. Also, I have no experience in analog design, so I will consider posting my schematic.

Comment: Think about how long it takes a meter's needle to stabilize (I'm sure there are videos if you don't have an analogue meter) <-- is that too long or is it Goldilocks?

Comment: This can't be answered unless you provide more info.  You never define "good enough".  What sort of precision and accuracy do you need?  What is your sample rate?  How much error are you willing to tolerate.  FWIW, you'll probably be fine with that inamp.